# How to set background color of console in python?

Tags: python, console

My question is clear. How can I set background color of console with python ?
I know that we can set background color of console in C#.
So I thought that python can do it, too.
But how ?
I'm on Windows and I use python 2.7.3.
Thanks...

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible but I would imagine overriding settings the user may have placed on their terminal window for good reason would be considered rude at best.

Answer (score 8):

You can set the Windows cmd console color with [the `color` command](http://ss64.com/nt/color.html), passing it from Python via `os.system`:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('color 1f') # sets the background to blue
```

For Linux terminals, use [the `setterm` command](http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/482):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('setterm -background white -foreground white -store')
```

Comment: Note:  The terminal colors are not restored on python exit because they were changed through a system call.  After exiting, you probably should restore them:   `os.system('color')`.

Comment: foreground and background both to white?

Comment: Thanks! With this I removed 50 lines from my code.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on  the shell and terminal emulator you are working running on. For `bash` this should work on ubuntu's terminal.

```
import os
color = 'blue'
os.system('setterm -term linux -back $'+color+' -fore white -clear')
```